# Efficient way to update progress of long task while processing a task with Mono&Flux

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I tried to make a method for long task which sends events of progress.

The method implemented by using Flux and Mono.

I figured out two ways to do it.

But I can't decide which approach is more efficient and elegant, or the other one.

Way 1.

```
var progressEvents = Sinks.Many<Progress> = Sinks.many().multicast()

fun doLongTask(taskFile : Mono<File>) : Mono<Another> {
   return taskFile.map{ file ->
      progressEvents.tryEmit(Progress("1"))
      doSomething(file)    
   }.map{ something ->
      progressEvents.tryEmit(Progress("2"))
      doAnother(something)
   }
}
```

Way2.

```
var progressEvents = Sinks.Many<Progress> = Sinks.many().multicast()

fun doLongTask(taskFile : Mono<File>) : Mono<Another> {
   var doSomeMap = taskFile.map{ file ->
      doSomething(file)    
   }.share()
   doSomeMap.map{ something -> Progress("1")}.subscribe{progressEvents::tryEmit}
   var doAnotherMap = doSomeMap.map{ something ->
      doAnother(something)
   }.share()
   doAnotherMap.map{ another -> Progress("2")}.subscribe{progressEvents::tryEmit}
   return doAnotherMap
}
```

Comment: I don't think the sharing in way 2 brings much more than overhead to the table, and so I would go with way 1. Get into the habit of checking the `EmitResult` returned by `tryEmit` though, or to at least document why it is fine not checking it in a comment.

Comment: @SimonBaslé Well, I want to keep it simple, inside of map or flatMap. '''emitNext''' could be a better option. anyway tryEmit or emitNext is not the point.

Comment: it is not good code for checking some emit result, inside of map or flatmap. Additionally it is not related with main data.

Comment: In addition, I want to avoid callbacks.

Comment: I'm just telling you as a side note (hence the comment format) that getting in the bad habit of not checking that `EmitResult`, you will end up shooting yourself in the foot ¯\_(ツ)_/¯